# Read and understand the spray-routing DSL

Tags: scala, spray, spray-routing

I am new to spray. 
I have work with several strange (for me) programming languages like python, JQuery, etc...  With them I could at least understand what some code segment do. 
Unfortunately with Spray, I can not read and understand even a simple code.

Could some one please help me to read (describe with word, what the code do) the following simple code block.

**Note:** Very high level I know, this will pick the url parameter and add them together. But what I want is, understand this code block crystal clearly, as I could teach to someone else. `HNil, Directive1, Directive1, ::` are some what strange for me.

```
val twoIntParameters: Directive[Int :: Int :: HNil] =
  parameters('a.as[Int], 'b.as[Int])

val myDirective: Directive1[String] =
  twoIntParameters.hmap {
    case a :: b :: HNil => (a + b).toString
  }

// test `myDirective` using the testkit DSL
Get("/?a=2&b=5") ~> myDirective(x => complete(x)) ~> check {
  responseAs[String] === "7"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

spray-routing is build around the concept of [`Directive`](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.3/spray-routing/key-concepts/directives/).

You can think of a `Directive` as a transformation over an HTTP request.

The cardinality associated with a directive is the number of arguments is passes down the transform chain after performing the transformation.

`Directive0` is a directive that doesn't provide (or extract) any argument.

`Directive1[A]` provides one argument of type `A`.

`Directive[A :: B :: HNil]` provides 2 arguments of types `A` and `B`, or - to be more precise - provides an heterogeneous list made of `A` and `B` (the implementation is a [shapeless's `HList`](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless)).

Let's take the examples in your code

```
val twoIntParameters: Directive[Int :: Int :: HNil] =
  parameters('a.as[Int], 'b.as[Int])
```

You're defining a new directive that extracts two integers from the HTTP request, i.e. has the type `Directive[Int :: Int :: HNil]`.
The implementation simply leverages a directive provided already by spray, i.e. `parameters`.
`parameters` is a directive that allows to extract the query parameters from a HTTP request and convert them to a specific type, in this case `Int` for both parameters.

```
val myDirective: Directive1[String] =
  twoIntParameters.hmap {
    case a :: b :: HNil => (a + b).toString
  }
```

`myDirective` is a directive that extracts one parameter of type `String`.

Its implementation uses the previously defined `twoIntParameters` directive and maps over its result, applying a transformation to it.
In this case we're taking the two `Int`, summing them and turning the result into a `String`.

So, what's with the `hmap`? That's just a way provided by spray of working with Directives that return a shapeless `HList`. `hmap` requires a function that `HList` to anything, in this case a `String`.

`HList`s can be pattern matched over, just like a normal scala `List`, and that's what you're seeing in the example.

Finally, this is just an idea of how directives work from a functional point of view.
If you want to understand the fine details of the DSL syntax, you will have to dig a little further and read about the [Magnet Pattern](http://spray.io/blog/2012-12-13-the-magnet-pattern/).

Comment: Is this correct...?

1) Directive definition (`Directive[Int :: Int :: HNil]` ) always contain information about parameters it return (extract)

2) And always its input is the HTTP-request (`RequestContext`)

Answer (score 0):

Here I found a very good workshop.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XPuOlpWEvmw